# which event is fired after the action event?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to display the header of the modal popup with the value `chatBean.selectedUser`. The thing that happens is that `onclick` event is fired before `action` event so the page is not refreshed when the `onclick` event is fired. Hence I cannot get the header of modal pop up as the value contained in `chatBean.selectedUser`. Is there anyway that I can display the header of modal popup with the value `chatbean.selectedUser` after that the page is submitted?

Here is the relevant part of the view:

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{chatBean.selectedUser}" id="select">
        <f:selectItems value="#{chatBean.friendList}" var="users" itemLabel="#{users.firstName}" itemValue="#{users.firstName}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:commandButton id="basic"  value="Basic" onclick="dlg.show()" type="button"  action="#{chatBean.refresh}"></p:commandButton>      
    <p:dialog id="modalDialog" header="#{chatBean.selectedUser}" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" height="100">  
        <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />  
        <h:inputText></h:inputText>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should show the dialog only when the action is completed, not before. Use the `oncomplete` attribute instead.

```
<p:commandButton ... oncomplete="dlg.show()" />
```

Don't forget to explicitly update the dialog's content before opening it. I don't see that anywhere in your code. Perhaps you're using `RequestContext#update()` or something, but normally you'd use `update` attribute for this.

```
<p:commandButton ... update="modelDialog" oncomplete="dlg.show()" />
```

Also, the `type="button"` is strange. This way the action wouldn't be invoked at all, but perhaps that's just a careless leftover of experimentation. Remove it.

Comment: Wow it works. But can I make the background accessible when modal dialog box pops up. Everything in the background is disabled when modal dialog box pops up.

Comment: That's normal in a modal dialog. Just make it non-modal by removing `modal="true"`. See also the showcase example and the documentation.

Comment: Is it possible to open multiple modal dialog boxes if I remove `model="true"`.Actually I am trying to design a facebook like chat system using JSF.